# extracting values from specific field in a .txt file

Tags: python, split, sys

I tried to extract values from a specified field from a file.

For example a file thing.txt has the following content

**apple juice bear box**

**bee snake water air**

**speed height length weight**

When I enter : python program.py 4 thing.txt

The output should be

> box
>
> air
>
> weight

```
import sys 
WordInd = sys.argv[1]
WordList=[]
NList=[]

with open(sys.argv[2])as my_file:
    for line in my_file:
        WordList=line.split(' ',int(WordInd))
        NList.append(WordList[int(WordInd)-1])
        
i = 0
while i<len(NList):
    print(NList[i])
    i+=1
```

The program works fine with python program.py 1 thing.txt to python program.py 4 thing.txt

However, When I tried to extract the last word of each line, there are extra space between each output. For example:

box

(extra space)

air

(extra space)

weight(extra space)

(extra space)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
import sys 
WordInd = sys.argv[1]
WordList=[]
NList=[]

with open(sys.argv[2])as my_file:
    for line in my_file:
        line=line[:-1] #to remove "\n" from end of the line 
        WordList=line.split(' ',int(WordInd))
        NList.append(WordList[int(WordInd)-1])

i = 0
while i<len(NList):
    print(NList[i])
    i+=1
```

Comment: what does "\n" means

Comment: "\n" represents newline character.

Answer (score 0):

If you only want last words of each line you can also try:

```
print([line.strip().split()[-1] for line in open('file.txt','r') if line!='\n'])
```

output:

```
['box', 'air', 'weight']
```